# Load Tensorflowjs from json object not json

Tags: javascript, json, tensorflow.js

I am trying to load a Tensorflowjs model using the model.json which is an in memory browser side object.

https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#loadLayersModel

One approach may be to return the json from a dummy fetch method.

> fetchFunc (Function) A function used to override the window.fetch
>   function.

Alternatively, it is possible to create a custom IOHandler, but there is very little documentation on this.

> An tf.io.IOHandler object that loads model artifacts with its load
>   method.

Does anyone know how to achieve this using the tensorflow load methods?

```
var modelJson = "{...ModelAndWeightsConfig}";

//Do something here to load it.

var newModel =  tf.loadLayersModel("/model_0/model.json", {
                    onProgress: onProgressCallback}).then(model =>{});
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch the models

```
    var fetchPromise = function(url,p1,p2,) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            fetch(url)
                    .then(response => {
                        resolve(response);
                    }).catch(err =>{
                        reject();
                    });
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can write your own `IOHandler` to load the model. Check out the definition of an `IOHandler` [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/81225adc2fcf6fcf633b4119e4b89a3bf55be824/tfjs-core/src/io/types.ts#L363). You have to implement the `load` function that returns a [`Promise<ModelArtifacts>`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/81225adc2fcf6fcf633b4119e4b89a3bf55be824/tfjs-core/src/io/types.ts#L348).

That means, to load a model saved by the [file IOHandler](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/9cb4d53fa20dd58349a131c834c3054906dbb897/tfjs-node/src/io/file_system.ts), you can check out the source code and reimplement the load function yourself.

**Code Sample**

Here is example to get you started. The `load()` part is mostly copied from the [`loadJSONModel`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/9cb4d53fa20dd58349a131c834c3054906dbb897/tfjs-node/src/io/file_system.ts#L165) function from the file IOHandler. Basically, the JSON string is passed as an argument and then used when the `load` function is called by Tensorflow.js.

```js
export class JSONHandler implements tfc.io.IOHandler {
  constructor(jsonString) {
     this.jsonString = jsonString;
  }
  async load() {
    const modelJSON = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    const modelArtifacts: tfc.io.ModelArtifacts = {
      modelTopology: modelJSON.modelTopology,
      format: modelJSON.format,
      generatedBy: modelJSON.generatedBy,
      convertedBy: modelJSON.convertedBy
    };
    if (modelJSON.weightsManifest != null) {
      // load weights (if they exist)
    }
    if (modelJSON.trainingConfig != null) {
      modelArtifacts.trainingConfig = modelJSON.trainingConfig;
    }
    if (modelJSON.userDefinedMetadata != null) {
      modelArtifacts.userDefinedMetadata = modelJSON.userDefinedMetadata;
    }
    return modelArtifacts;
  }
}
```

To use the model, you can then create an instance of it and pass it to the load function:

```js
const modelJson = '{ ... }';
const handler = new JSONHandler(modelJson);
const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(handler);
```

Comment: hi, i seem to get the following error, `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: specs is not iterable
    at Module.decodeWeights (io_utils.js:105)`, is there a way to resolve this